# Interpreting item click in ListView

Tags: android, listview, callback, click, listener

I'm working on my first Android project, and I created a menu via the XML method.  My activity is pretty basic, in that it loads the main layout (containing a ListView with my String array of options).  Here's the code inside my Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // allow stuff to happen when a list item is clicked
    ListView ls = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    ls.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // @todo
        }
    });
}
```

Within the onItemClick callback handler, I'd like to check which item was clicked, and load a new menu based upon that.

Question 1: How do I go about figuring out which item was clicked?  I can't find any straightforward examples on retrieving/testing the `id` value of the clicked item.

Question 2: Once I have the `id` value, I assume I can just call the `setContentView` method again to change to another layout containing my new menu.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on my first Android
>   project, and I created a menu via the
>   XML method.

Actually, Android has a separate concept of menus, so I'd be a bit wary about describing your UI in those terms.

> How do I go about figuring out which
>   item was clicked?

If you are using an `ArrayAdapter`, the `position` parameter passed to `onItemClick()` is the index into your array.

> I assume I can just call the
>   setContentView method again to change
>   to another layout containing my new
>   menu. Is that correct?

Yes, though there may be better approaches to the UI that will be more Android-y. Most Android applications do not start off with some sort of multi-layer navigation before you actually get to do something.